# TypeError: Cannot read property '$filter' of undefined

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I am showing the json object on the UI when user click on a link, below is the exception it is showing

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '$filter' of undefined
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/5NOBQ3rzE3EFwTnuLbXG?p=preview

sample js code:

```
app.controller('BaseCtrl', ['$scope','$http','$filter', function($scope,$http,$filter) {

$scope.myList = [{"sId":100,"spread":"21x","owner":"Michael","labels":"deffered incomplete"},
{"sId":101,"spread":"34","owner":"Steve","labels":"complete"},
{"sId":102,"spread":"90s","owner":"John","labels":"tested"},
{"sId":103,"spread":"332","owner":"Dex","labels":"complete deffered"}  
];

//$scope.myListObj;
$scope.showList = function(myListObj){
  console.log("myListObj " + JSON.stringify(myListObj));
  //  $scope.defferedList = $scope.myListObj.filter(function( obj ) {
    $scope.defferedList =  JSON.stringify($scope.myListObj).filter(function( obj ) {
      console.log(obj.labels.includes('deffered'));
      return obj.labels.includes('deffered');
}); 
console.log("defferedList :: " +  $scope.defferedList);
}
}]);
```

I have included `'$http','$filter'` in the controller.Any inputs?

Comment: I don't get that error, I see: ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined```

Which makes total sense. The filter function is being used on a stringified value, which won't work. Also, you aren't even using $filter. What is showList supposed to be doing, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a quick change, as I think this is what you actually want.

Basically, you aren't using $filter, and you're trying to filter on a type that does not have that method within its prototype. If you don't stringify, it will work as intended.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('BaseCtrl', ['$scope','$http', function($scope,$http) {
  
  $scope.myList = [{"sId":100,"spread":"21x","owner":"Michael","labels":"deffered incomplete"},
{"sId":101,"spread":"34","owner":"Steve","labels":"complete"},
{"sId":102,"spread":"90s","owner":"John","labels":"tested"},
{"sId":103,"spread":"332","owner":"Dex","labels":"complete deffered"}  
];

//$scope.myListObj;
$scope.showList = function(myListObj){
  console.log("myListObj " + JSON.stringify(myListObj));
  //  $scope.defferedList = $scope.myListObj.filter(function( obj ) {
    $scope.defferedList =  myListObj.filter(function( obj ) {
   console.log(obj.labels && obj.labels.includes('deffered'));
      return obj.labels && obj.labels.includes('deffered');
}); 
console.log("defferedList :: ", $scope.defferedList);
}
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
 
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <style>
    .my-col-50{float:left;}
  </style>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="BaseCtrl">
  <div class="container">
   
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="showList(myList)"> 
    Click here</a>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When i have null in the element value it is throwing the error TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of null. Updated demo : next.plnkr.co/edit/eJO1wiKJpnBMpfoe .Any inputs ?

Comment: That makes sense, too, as you cannot call filter on null. I'll update my answer to account for that.

Comment: If it solves your question, please accept that answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem isn't with $filter The error I am seeing is

> Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

This is referring to the javascript method [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) not AngularJS's '$filter'. Filter is a javascript method that can be called on an array. It also doesn't appear that there a need to do JSON.stringify here. Try this instead

```
$scope.defferedList =  $scope.myListObj.filter(function( obj ) {
    console.log(obj.labels.includes('deffered'));
    return obj.labels.includes('deffered');
});
```

Comment: "This will return a list with true or false values."  This is not correct. Filter method returns an array of items for which the iteratee returned true. His original logic worked fine in that regard. Your version will, as well, since an object is technically truthy, but it's an unnecessary if statement.

Comment: It is correct. `return obj.labels.includes('deffered')` will return true or false based on whether or not each object's labels property includes the string 'deffered'. I ran the code `$scope.defferedList` ends up being a list of true of false values.

Comment: run the code within my answer, and read the mdn: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: You are correct. I was placing `console.log(obj.labels.includes('deffered)` in place of the return statement which is why I was getting that result

Answer (score 1):

This can be corrected by writing the showList method as below

```
  $scope.showList = function(myListObj) {
  console.log("myListObj " + JSON.stringify(myListObj));
  $scope.defferedList = myListObj.filter(function(obj) {
      console.log(obj.labels.includes('deffered'));
      return obj.labels.includes('deffered');
    });
    console.log("defferedList :: " + $scope.defferedList);
  }
```

The error was basically because you were trying to apply the filter operation intended for arrays type on the Stringified version of $scope.myListObj instead of actual array.

Also since you are using filter method of array object, you would not require "$filter" as dependency for the module.